# How to make a custom config in Spigot

Tags: java, config, bukkit

Ive always wondered if there is a much more simple way to create a custom config or custom YAML file with the Spigot/Bukkit api please answer me but say if there is a easier and simpler way to do it :D thanks

Comment: Look up Bukkit/spigot forums, there are plenty of people asking this and even more answers. In short, to create a cusom config you will have to use the YAMLConfiguration API comming with Bukkit and furthermore spigot to parse a blank text file into a YAML file, then you can edit/add/remove values as you please and then save them on the file. All that excpet the file creation is done through the YAML apit.

Comment: Np :- ) Feel free to ask if you have any other question. Also consider aproving the answer that suits this thread the most from the "answers" sectiion.

Comment: @Hydrox Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't edit your title to state it is answered, use the checkbox below the answer that answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you right, you want to create a Yaml config file with your own things in. This is very simple.

`saveDefaultConfig();` and just have a config.yml in your project with whatever you want in it (As long as the syntax is still correct) and it will save and load that Yaml file.

Comment: No i didnt mean this i ment how to create a custom actual YAML file in java with the bukkit/spigot libary that i can use as a config

Comment: This does make a config but if you want another Yaml file look into the FileConfiguration class.

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my main Class:

```
        File locations = new File("plugins/GlobalSystem", "locations.yml");
        if (!locations.exists()) {
            try {
                locations.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FileConfiguration loc = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(locations);
            loc.set("spawn.Welt", "Welt");
            loc.set("spawn.X", 0);
            loc.set("spawn.Y", 100);
            loc.set("spawn.Z", 0);
            loc.set("spawn.Yaw", 0);
            loc.set("spawn.Pitch", 0);
            loc.set("reallife.Welt", "Welt");
            loc.set("reallife.X", 0);
            loc.set("reallife.Y", 100);
            loc.set("reallife.Z", 0);
            loc.set("reallife.Yaw", 0);
            loc.set("reallife.Pitch", 0);
            loc.set("acidisland.Welt", "Welt");
            loc.set("acidisland.X", 0);
            loc.set("acidisland.Y", 100);
            loc.set("acidisland.Z", 0);
            loc.set("acidisland.Yaw", 0);
            loc.set("acidisland.Pitch", 0);
            loc.set("skypvp.Welt", "Welt");
            loc.set("skypvp.X", 0);
            loc.set("skypvp.Y", 100);
            loc.set("skypvp.Z", 0);
            loc.set("skypvp.Yaw", 0);
            loc.set("skypvp.Pitch", 0);
            loc.set("spiele.Welt", "Welt");
            loc.set("spiele.X", 0);
            loc.set("spiele.Y", 100);
            loc.set("spiele.Z", 0);
            loc.set("spiele.Yaw", 0);
            loc.set("spiele.Pitch", 0);
            loc.set("silenthub.Welt", "Welt");
            loc.set("silenthub.X", 0);
            loc.set("silenthub.Y", 100);
            loc.set("silenthub.Z", 0);
            loc.set("silenthub.Yaw", 0);
            loc.set("silenthub.Pitch", 0);
            try {
                loc.save(locations);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

If you now want to read something out you can use for example this:

```
    FileConfiguration cfg = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(new File("plugins/GlobalSystem", "locations.yml"));
    Location loc = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(cfg.getString("spawn.Welt")), cfg.getDouble("spawn.X"), cfg.getDouble("spawn.Y"), cfg.getDouble("spawn.Z"));
    loc.setYaw((float) cfg.getDouble("spawn.Yaw"));
    loc.setPitch((float) cfg.getDouble("spawn.Pitch"));
```

To write in the File:

```
    File file = new File("plugins/GlobalSystem", "locations.yml");
    FileConfiguration cfg = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
    Location loc = Player.getLocation();
    cfg.set("spawn.Welt", loc.getWorld().getName());
    cfg.set("spawn.X", loc.getX());
    cfg.set("spawn.Y", loc.getY());
    cfg.set("spawn.Z", loc.getZ());
    cfg.set("spawn.Yaw", (double) loc.getYaw());
    cfg.set("spawn.Pitch", (double) loc.getYaw());
    try {
        cfg.save(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I hope this helps you and sorry for my bad English ;)